# Token recognition using strtok()

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to read a file and separate left hand side of equal sign from right hand side and see if left hand side is "HOME". It finds that first token is "HOME" but fails to say if it equals "HOME". Basically the line written in file is "`HOME = /cs/nsf`".

What's going wrong?

```
while (fgets(buffer,80,file)) //while end of file
{
   char *token = strtok(buffer,"=");
   printf("first token: %s\n",token); //this correctly prints "HOME"
   if (strcmp(token,"HOME") == 0)
   {
       printf("it doesn't get here");
       token = strtok(NULL,"\n");         //this should return "/cs/nsf" but it doesn't;
       if (token == NULL || strcmp(token," ") == 0)
       {
           fprintf(stderr,"HOME isn't initialised\n")
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the contents of the file.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't printing "HOME "?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first printf prints `"HOME "`. You should use `"= \t"` as your token string, to have it return `"HOME"` (and not any whitespace).

Answer (score 3):

Well, since you used `=` as the only delimiter for `strtok`, your first token will include the space before the `=` in the input string. So the first token you parse is actually `"HOME "`. That's what your `printf` is printing. You just can't see the space at the end.

Obviously, `"HOME "` is not the same as `"HOME"`. Add space to the list of delimiters for `strtok`.

Answer (score 2):

It must be printing "first token: HOME " (with a space after HOME).

Answer (score 1):

You need to trim the whitespace from  the end of your token. It is likely printing `"HOME "` (note the extra space).

Answer (score 0):

There's a blank after HOME in the file.

Use:

```
printf("first token <<%s>>\n", token);
```

to see the problem.  Then strip leading and trailing blanks before comparing.  Note that explicitly marking the beginning and ending of a string with something like `<<` and `>>` (you can tell I don't work with XML text very much) makes it easier to see leading and trailing blanks and other unexpected effects.  I find it a valuable technique all the time.

Answer (score 0):

```
HOME = /cs/nsf
```

so actually the first token before is not `"HOME"` but `"HOME "` - note the space on the left.

Either use `" = "` as the second argument of `strtok()` or write `strcmp(token, "HOME ")` to achieve what you want.

Comment: @EricPostpischil did I mention I hate Markdown? :P